# How to create new maven Lifecycle job to maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I need to have a new maven Lifecycle job in my maven project with all current jobs: install/clean/test/compile/package/...

This Lifecycle  job needs to do update over the DB using SQL and JAVA.

How can I create a new maven job to my project with Java/SQL code running it ?

I tried to look for an answer in the web and I didn't find any.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "Lifecycle job"? Do you mean a goal or a Maven plugin?

Comment: @JFMeier Yes, I need an example how to build such goal

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would search on the internet if there is already Maven plugin that does the job. There are plenty of it.

If not, you can write one yourself (https://www.baeldung.com/maven-plugin).

Comment: Could you please share me an example or tell me what should I search please ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the link in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did, the explanation is good, i'm looking for examples of using SQL and Java like you said

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you. The link explains how you write a Maven plugin _in Java_. From Java, you can call SQL if you want to. What are you missing?

Comment: I looking for some best practice of this for making things easier and fast

Comment: You asked how to create a "Maven job", and I gave you a tutorial. The tutorial describes best practises how to write a Maven plugin.

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to have a new plugin/goal in maven which is using my JPA layer in order to create DB tables and insert fake data

Comment: Then I guess you need to ask a new question which more detailed information, including examples of what you want to achieve.